# Fechas con ceros al insertar en un campo de fecha

Tags: php

Quisiera saber si me pudieran ayudar, por favor, ya que a la hora de insertar la hora me da `0000-00-00 00:00:00` y la verdad no entiendo por qué.

Se supone que debería darme la hora en tiempo real.

Mi campo `Fecha_pedido` es de tipo `timestamp` y en predeterminado de tipo `current_timestamp()`.

Nota: en la variable de `$fecha` solo me deja colocar `date("Y-m-d")`, porque si coloco `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` ya no me agrega ningún dato.

Sin embargo, si pongo un `print_r` aún con la segunda forma, sí me la da pero como digo no me la agrega.

**compras.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conectar.php';
           $arreglo=$_SESSION['carrito'];

            date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
            $fecha=date("Y-m-d");
             //print_r($fecha);die();
           $Numeroventa=0;
           $re=$Conexion->prepare("select * from Pedido order by Numeroventa DESC limit 1") or die(mysql_error());
           $re->execute();
           $resultado = $re->fetchAll();
           foreach ($resultado as $f) {
                        $Numeroventa=$f['Numeroventa'];
           }
           if($Numeroventa==0){
            $Numeroventa=1;
           }else{
            $Numeroventa=$Numeroventa+1;
           }
           for($i=0; $i<count($arreglo);$i++){
             $agregar = "INSERT INTO Pedido (Numeroventa, Fecha_pedido, Id_producto, Precio, cantidad, Id_usuario, Total) values(
                 ".$Numeroventa.",
                 ".$fecha.",
                 '".$arreglo[$i]['Id_producto']."',
                 '".$arreglo[$i]['Precio']."',
                 '".$arreglo[$i]['cantidad']."',
                 '".$arreglo[$i]['Id_usuario']."',
                 '".$arreglo[$i]['Precio']*$arreglo[$i]['cantidad']."'
                 
                )";
$resultado = $Conexion->prepare($agregar);
    $resultado ->execute();

             
            

           }
           unset($_SESSION['carrito']);
?>
```

Comment: Intenta insertar la fecha agregando `'` como lo tienes con los otros campos

Comment: Tu código puede sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL). Ya que estás usando `mysqli::prepare()` deberías usar marcadores en vez de concatenar cadenas. Además, si quieres que tu campo `Fecha_pedido` use el valor por defecto (`current_timestamp()`), debes excluirlo del `INSERT`. Además, quizá deberías plantearte un `SELECT MAX(Numeroventa) FROM Pedido`.

Comment: Otra errata que pasé por alto (por no desplazar la ventana de código): estás usando `mysql_error()` con los métodos orientados a objeto de `mysqli`. Deberías plantearte usar [`$Conexion->error`](https://php.net/es/mysqli.error) en su lugar.

Comment: Te recomendaría que en tu campo ```Fecha_pedido``` en lugar de tipo ```timestamp``` pongas tipo ```DATETIME``` para almacenar **Y-m-d H:i:s**.

Comment: @Tony_Bielo , está usando una propiedad bien conocida de ese tipo de campos para registrar de manera automática el momento de la creación del registro (y también la última modificación si se desea). Antes de la versión 5.6.5 solo funcionaba con ese tipo de campos: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Comment: Por cierto, el motivo por el que te guarda la fecha con ceros con un `date` y con el otro te falla es porque el primero resulta en una operación matemática que da como resultado una fecha inválida y el segundo en un error de sintaxis (los dos puntos de los separadores de la hora no se pueden usar como operadores). Mañana agregaré eso a mi respuesta explicándolo con un ejemplo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia te lo agradezco

Comment: Actualicé la respuesta. Espero que te fuera de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Quita

```
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    $fecha=date("Y-m-d");
     //print_r($fecha);die();
```

Añade los siguiente

```
$tz = 'America/México_City';
$timestamp = time();
$dt = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz)); //first argument "must" be a string
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp); //adjust the object to correct timestamp
//Creamos las variables necesarias
$fecha=$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: me sale el siguiente error Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTimeZone::__construct(): Unknown or bad timezone (America/México_City) in C:\xampp\htdocs\El grano\cliente\compras.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\El grano\cliente\compras.php(8): DateTimeZone->__construct('America/M\xC3\xA9xico...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\El grano\cliente\compras.php on line 8

Comment: quitale el acento a México a ver

Answer (score 0):

Estás haciendo un uso incorrecto del valor por defecto del campo `Fecha_pedido`. Para que éste sea usado (`current_timestamp()`) el campo `Fecha_pedido` **no debe aparecer** en el `INSERT INTO`.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo podría quedar el bucle de inserción:

```
<?php
/* Preparamos la consulta UNA ÚNICA VEZ */
$agregar = "
    INSERT INTO Pedido (
        Numeroventa,
        Id_producto,
        Precio,
        cantidad,
        Id_usuario,
        Total
    ) VALUES (
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?
    )
";
$consulta = $Conexion->prepare($agregar);
foreach ($arreglo as $elemento) {
    /* Asignamos los valores en cada iteración */
    $resultado = $consulta->exec(
        $Numeroventa,
        $elemento['Id_producto'],
        $elemento['Precio'],
        $elemento['cantidad'],
        $elemento['Id_usuario'],
        $elemento['Precio'] * $elemento['cantidad']
    );
    /* En caso de error mostramos el mensaje */
    if ($resultado === false) {
        die(htmlspecialchars(implode(": ", $consulta->errorInfo)));
    }
}
```

Como puedes ver, he realizado varias mejoras adicionales:

- Las consultas preparadas te permite preparar una única vez la consulta SQL y, posteriormente, ejecutar la consulta múltiples veces con diferentes valores en cada marcador.
- Tu código sufre los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL). He modificado la consulta para que haga uso de marcadores.
- He comprobado el resultado de la consulta SQL para que muestre un mensaje en caso de que ésta falle.

Si por cualquier motivo deseas introducir una fecha en el campo `Fecha_pedido`, recuerda que debes usar un marcador de tipo `s` (`string` o cadena de caracteres) y el formato de fecha `AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (`date(Y-m-d H:i:s)`).

PD: No necesitas almacenar el valor `Total` como un campo más de la tabla ya que éste se puede calcular siempre a partir de `Precio` y `cantidad`.

---

## TL;DR

Terminaré explicando el motivo por el que usando `date("Y-m-d")` funciona pero te inserta una fecha `0000-00-00 00:00:00` y `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` no te inserta nada en la tabla.

Empecemos destacado que estás insertando las fechas en la consulta SQL sin ponerlas entre comillas.

Cuando ejecutas la siguiente instrucción:

```
SELECT 2022-01-11
```

El resultado será ([ver en línea](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uR3hEGTdAw3o5hzNb7rrwh/0)):

| 2022-01-11 |
| --- |
| 2010 |

Debido a que estás realizando la operación matemática 2022 menos 01 menos 11 (que da como resultado 2010).

Como el número 2010 no se puede convertir a fecha, produce un `NULL` (fecha cero) que es representado con esa fecha que es inválida (nunca ha existido ni el mes ni el día 0):

```
INSERT INTO pruebas (fecha) VALUES (2022-01-11)
```

El resultado sería ([ver en línea](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uR3hEGTdAw3o5hzNb7rrwh/1)):

| fecha |
| --- |
| 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |

Dependiendo del valor de los parámetros de configuración [`ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates), [`NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_in_date%60) y/o [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date%60) podrás trabajar con fechas inválidas convirtiéndolas a fechas nulas o no.

En la versiones más modernas de MySQL (a partir de la 5.7) el valor por defecto configurado incluye los siguientes parámetros: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, **`NO_ZERO_IN_DATE`**, **`NO_ZERO_DATE`**, `ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO`, `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` y `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`. Por lo que a partir de MySQL 5.7 se generará un error y no se insertará una fecha nula en la tabla.

Por último, realizar la siguiente consulta genera siempre un error:

```
SELECT 2022-01-11 22:30:01
```

El resultado es ([ver en línea](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uR3hEGTdAw3o5hzNb7rrwh/2)) el siguiente mensaje de error:

> ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '22:30:01' at line 1

Es debido a anteriormente el separador de la fecha (el guion `-`) fue confundido con el operador resta, pero no existe el operador `:`. Por ese motivo la consulta SQL siempre generará un error, abortándose la inserción.

En resumen: no se podrá insertar correctamente ningún valor de fecha y/o hora sin poner entre comillas la información.

Comment: Hola Oscar, excelente respuesta, como siempre. Aunque me temo que este código no funcionará, pues viendo el código de OP, está usando `$resultado = $re->fetchAll();`, lo cual indicaría que **su conexión podría ser PDO, no mysqli**, aunque en otra parte, como señalas, usa funciones de mysql_ (antecesor de mysqli). Convendría que OP aclare cuál de los dos controladores está usando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apunte. No hay por donde coger el código  pero todo apunta a que es PDO como bien indicas. Mañana hago los cambios.

Comment: @OscarGarcia te lo agradeceria mucho, gracias.

Comment: He migrado el código a PDO con los mínimos cambios y, además, he agregado una explicación detallada del motivo por el que aparece la fecha cero.